# Finding the root value of a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have an array which stores the relations of values, which makes several trees something like:

[image]

So, in this case, my array would be (root, linked to)

(8,3)
(8,10)
(3,1)
(3,6)
(6,4)
(6,7)
(10,14)
(14,13)

And i'd like to set all the root values in the array to the main root in the tree (in all trees):

(8,3)
(8,1)
(8,6)
(8,4)
(8,7)
(8,10)
(8,14)
(8,13)

What algorithm should i investigate?

Comment: The "main" root is the only value that never appears on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 7):

1) Make a list of all the unique first elements of the tuples.

2) Remove any that also appear as the second element of a tuple.

3) You'll be left with the root (8 here). Replace the first elements of all tuples with this value.

---

EDIT:

A more complicated approach that will work with multiple trees would be as follows.

First, convert to a parent lookup table:

```
1 -> 3
3 -> 8
4 -> 6
6 -> 3
7 -> 6
10 -> 8
13 -> 14
14 -> 10
```

Next, run "find parent with path compression" on each element:

1)

```
1 -> 3 -> 8
```

gives

```
1 -> 8
3 -> 8
4 -> 6
...
```

3)

```
3 -> 8
```

4)

```
4 -> 6 -> 3 -> 8
```

gives

```
1 -> 8
3 -> 8
4 -> 8
6 -> 8
7 -> 6
...
```

6)

```
6 -> 8 (already done)
```

7)

```
7 -> 6 -> 8
```

etc.

Result:

```
1 -> 8
3 -> 8
4 -> 8
6 -> 8
7 -> 8
...
```

Then convert this back to the tuple list:

```
(8,1)(8,3)(8,4)...
```

---

The find parent with path compression algorithm is as `find_set` would be for disjoint set forests, e.g.

```
int find_set(int x) const
{
    Element& element = get_element(x);
    int& parent = element.m_parent;
    if(parent != x)
    {
        parent = find_set(parent);
    }
    return parent;
}
```

The key point is that path compression helps you avoid a lot of work. In the above, for example, when you do the lookup for `4`, you store `6 -> 8`, which makes later lookups referencing `6` faster.

Comment: Can he use a BFS to make the list?

Comment: @David using BFS would imply that you have to prepare some graph structure, which in this case would be an overkill. The only thing you need here is a collection with some sort of contains()

Comment: Easy way would be to use something like a std::set (in C++), or your language's equivalent.

Comment: @stuart As my array has several trees, if i do what you said the result is empty.

Comment: @Gabriel: Hope the second attempt is better, I missed the point about multiple trees the first time!

Comment: @StuartGolodetz i have my lookup table but dont get how to implement the find parent nor the union-find algorithm shown in Wikipedia (which shares the same concept). I'm puzzled @_@

Comment: @Gabriel: You don't need to implement union-find. The implementation for find-parent is as in my answer.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Let me see if i undestand the algorithm,:
1. Input a lookup value (in my case, the left values).
2. Get the parent of that value (right value).
3. If parent is different to lookup value, input parent.
4. Return parent.

Comment: The algorithm is essentially: (1) Convert the pairs you've got into a representation that is easier to work with, namely a child -> parent lookup table. (2) Work out the ultimate ancestor of each child and set that to be its new parent (but use path compression to minimise the amount of work you do). (3) Convert your modified lookup table back to the actual representation you're after.

Comment: The union-find stuff is a distraction - I only mentioned it because path compression is commonly used in the implementation of disjoint set forests.

Answer (score 0):

So assume you have a list of tuples representing the points:

```
def find_root(ls):
  child, parent, root = [], [], []
  for node in ls:
    parent.append(node[0])
    child.append(node[1])

  for dis in parent: 
    if (!child.count(dis)): 
      root.append(dis)

  if len(root) > 1 : return -1 # failure, the tree is not formed well

  for nodeIndex in xrange(len(ls)):
    ls[nodeIndex] = (root[0], ls[nodeIndex][1])

  return ls
```